# CUDA Matrix Multiplication using Parallel Reduction

Tags: c++, c, cuda, nvidia

I am quite new to CUDA programming, and I wanted to try an implementation of matrix multiplication using [Parallel Reduction](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf). I came up with this code, and would like clarifications on :

1. Why the code is returning incorrect results.
2. Why it is taking much longer to run than the method using shared memory described in Chapter 3, page 25 of the [CUDA C Programming Guide](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf).

For reference, I am running it on NVIDIA GeForce GTX 675M , which has a compute capability of 2.1 .

```
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"


#include <cuda.h>
#include <device_functions.h>

#include "cuda_runtime.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#define BLOCK_OPT 1024
typedef struct {
    int width;
    int height;
    int stride;
    float* elements;
}Matrix;





__global__ void MatMulOPT(Matrix A, Matrix B, Matrix C)
{
    __shared__ float result[BLOCK_OPT];
    int e = threadIdx.x;
    int row = blockIdx.x;
    int col = blockIdx.y;

    result[e] = A.elements[row*A.stride + e] * B.elements[e*B.stride + col];
    __syncthreads();
    if (e < 512)
    {
        result[e] += result[e + 512];
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if (e < 256)
    {
        result[e] += result[e + 256];
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if (e < 128)
    {
        result[e] += result[e + 128];
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if (e < 64)
    {
        result[e] += result[e + 64];
    }
    __syncthreads();

    if (e < 32)
    {
        result[e] += result[e + 32];
        result[e] += result[e + 16];
        result[e] += result[e + 8];
        result[e] += result[e + 4];
        result[e] += result[e + 2];
        result[e] += result[e + 1];
    }

    if (e == 0)C.elements[row*C.stride + col] = result[0];


}
void MatMulCPU(Matrix A, Matrix B, Matrix C)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < A.height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < B.width; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < B.height; k++)
            {
                C.elements[i*C.stride + j] += A.elements[i*A.stride+k] * B.elements[k*B.stride + j];
            }
        }
    }

}

float randomFloat()
{
    return (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
}

int main()
{
    clock_t begin, end;

    srand(time(NULL));

    //Common Setup
    float cpu_t = 0, gpu_t = 0;
    int x = 1024;
    int N = x * x;
    size_t size = N * sizeof(float);
    Matrix A;
    A.width = x;
    A.stride = x;
    A.height = x;
    A.elements = (float*)malloc(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        A.elements[i] = randomFloat();

    Matrix B;
    B.width = x;
    B.stride = x;
    B.height = x;
    B.elements = (float*)malloc(size);

    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        B.elements[j] = randomFloat();

    Matrix C;
    C.width = x;
    C.stride = x;
    C.height = x;
    C.elements = (float*)malloc(size);
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
        C.elements[k] = 0;

    Matrix D;
    D.width = x;
    D.stride = x;
    D.height = x;
    D.elements = (float*)malloc(size);
    for (int l = 0; l < N; l++)
        D.elements[l] = 0;

    //Execute CPU code & time it
     begin = clock();
    MatMulCPU(A, B, D);
    end = clock();
    cpu_t = (float)end - begin;


    // GPU setup

    Matrix d_A, d_B, d_C;
    d_A.width = x;
    d_A.stride = x;
    d_A.height = x;
    d_B.width = x;
    d_B.stride = x;
    d_B.height = x;
    d_C.width = x;
    d_C.stride = x;
    d_C.height = x;


    cudaMalloc(&d_A.elements, size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_A.elements, A.elements, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc(&d_B.elements, size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_B.elements, B.elements, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc(&d_C.elements, size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_C.elements, C.elements, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


    //Special Parameters
    int optBlockSize = BLOCK_OPT;
    dim3 optDimGrid(x, x);

    //Execute GPU Kernel and time it
    begin = clock();
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    MatMulOPT << <optDimGrid, optBlockSize >> > (d_A, d_B, d_C);
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    end = clock();
    gpu_t = (float)end - begin;

    cudaMemcpy(C.elements, d_C.elements, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);




    //Do a memcheck 
    bool passed = true;
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
    {
        //printf("%f ",C.elements[k]);
        if (fabs(C.elements[k] -D.elements[k] ) > 1e-6)
        {

            passed = false;
            printf("\nFAIL\n");
            printf("C[%d] = %f, D[%d] = %f\n",k,C.elements[k],k,D.elements[k]);
            break;
        }

    }
    printf("\n");
    if (passed)
        printf("PASSED\n");

    printf("CPU Elapsed Time: %f\n", cpu_t);
    printf("GPU Elapsed Time: %f\n", gpu_t);

    //Clear all GPU memory
    cudaFree(d_A.elements);
    cudaFree(d_B.elements);
    cudaFree(d_C.elements);
    //Clear all CPU memory
    free(A.elements);
    free(B.elements);
    free(C.elements);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Why the code is returning incorrect results.

In the last step of your reduction (`e < 32`) you are breaking with your method. This leads to race conditions on the same element of result, e.g.

```
result[e] += result[e + 16];
```

For `e==0` this means `read result[16]`, whereas in the same step/at the same time for `e==16` the operation means `write result[16]`.

To avoid the race condition you have two options:

- Use a pointer that is declared `volatile` like in the document you
  linked (p. 78) [edited]
- Continue the `if( e < ...)` as before  or transform all the ifs into a loop with:

  ```
  for(int size=blockdim.x/2; size>0; size/=2)
    if(e < size)
      ...
  ```

> 2. Why it is taking much longer to run than the method using shared memory described in Chapter 3, page 25 of the CUDA C Programming
>      Guide.

Accessing shared memory is much faster than accessing global memory. You are storing your intermediate result in shared memory, whereas the example you reference is storing the parts of the matrices to be read. In the example this is combined with loop tiling and every thread only loads one element of the whole tile from global memory, but later reads `TILE_WIDTH * 2` elements.

The higher performance of the example directly comes from a reduced time waiting for data to be loaded from global memory.

Comment: In the parallel reduction reference, they stated that, once you reach the last 32 threads, they behave as if they all belong to the same warp, and there is no need for synchronization. I am using almost the same code for reduction.

Comment: I have updated the answer; The difference between your code and the one in the Guide is the volatile pointer.